# Julia: find row in matrix

Tags: matrix, julia

Using Julia, I'd like to determine if a row is located in a matrix and (if applicable) where in the matrix the row is located. For example, in Matlab this can done with `ismember`:

```
a = [1 2 3];
B = [3 1 2; 2 1 3; 1 2 3; 2 3 1]
B =

 3     1     2
 2     1     3
 1     2     3
 2     3     1

ismember(B, a, 'rows')
ans =

 0
 0
 1
 0
```

From this, we can see `a` is located in row 3 of `B`. Is there a similar function to accomplish this in Julia?

Comment: I am interested in the version of this question where B is sorted using dictionnary order for its rows and where the search returns in logarithmic time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another pattern is using array comprehension:

```
julia> Bool[ a == B[i,:] for i=1:size(B,1) ]
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
false
false
true
false

julia> Int[ a == B[i,:] for i=1:size(B,1) ]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
0
0
1
0
```

Comment: This solution and the one by @freshfruit have similar runtimes, but this one seems to use less memory. Thanks to both!

Comment: the location of row `a` in `B` can be found with `find(Bool[ a == B[i,:] for i=1:size(B,1) ])`. However, this yields a result of type `Array{Int64, 1}` rather than `Int64`. Having the result be a `Array{Int64, 1}` causes headaches down the line. Is there a better way to get the result as an `Int64` other than `find(Bool[ a == B[i,:] for i=1:size(B,1) ])[1]`?

Comment: Following the other answers, findfirst() may be useful for this purpose. For example, `findfirst( [ a == B[i,:] for i=1:size(B,1) ] )` (with comprehension) or `findfirst( all( a .== B, 2 ) )` (with broadcasting). Also, we can drop Bool in front of [...] to make it a bit simpler :)

Answer (score 8):

You can also make use of array broadcasting by simply testing for equality (`.==`) without the use of comprehensions:

```
all(B .== a, dims=2)
```

Which gives you:

```
4x1 BitMatrix:
 0
 0
 1
 0
```

You can then use `findall` on this array:

```
findall(all(B .== a, 2))
```

However, this gives you a vector of `CartesianIndex` objects:

```
1-element Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(3, 1)
```

So if you expect to find multiple rows with the value defined in `a` you can either:

1. simplify this Vector by taking only the row index from each `CartesianIndex`:

   ```
   [cart_idx[1] for cart_idx in findall(all(B .== a, 2))]
   ```
2. or pass one dimensional `BitMatrix` to `findall` (as suggested by Shep Bryan in the comment):

   ```
   findall(all(B .== a, dims=2)[:, 1])
   ```

Either way you get an integer vector of column indices:

```
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
```

Comment: For Julia 1.7, I had to modify ``all(B .== a, 2)`` to ``all(B.==a, dims=2)``. Also ``find`` is not defined in Julia so I used ``findall(all(B .== a, dims=2)[:, 1])[1]``

Comment: Thanks, I will modify my answer, I wrote it long time ago (2015).

Answer (score 6):

how about:

```
matchrow(a,B) = findfirst(i->all(j->a[j] == B[i,j],1:size(B,2)),1:size(B,1))
```

returns `0` when no matching row, or first row number when there is one.

```
matchrow(a,B)
```

3

should be as "fast as possible" and pretty simple too.

Comment: This worked in Julia 1.1.0 whereas the other answers did not.

Comment: If you're in Julia >1.0 this function will return `nothing` when no matching row.

Answer (score 5):

Though Julia doesn't have a built-in function, its easy enough as a one-liner.

```
a = [1 2 3];
B = [3 1 2; 2 1 3; 1 2 3; 2 3 1]
ismember(mat, x, dims) = mapslices(elem -> elem == vec(x), mat, dims)
ismember(B, a, 2)  # Returns booleans instead of ints
```